# What is the cleanest way to get nextElementSibling (previousElementSibling) from MutationRecord?

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

I wonder what is the cleanest way to find surrounding `Element`s for given `MutationRecord`?

`MutationRecord` has `.nextSibling`, `.previousSibling` properties, but that may contain text nodes, and I need to get regular Element nodes.

Working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/tomalec/ceku2/

I tried using

```
mutation.addedNodes[0].previousElementSibling;
mutation.addedNodes[mutation.addedNodes.length - 1].nextElementSibling);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tomalec/Q2HFY/2/

However it looks a bit risky, and it does not work at all for removed ones.

```
mutation.removedNodes[0].previousElementSibling; //null
mutation.removedNodes[mutation.removedNodes.length - 1].nextElementSibling); //null
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tomalec/Q2HFY/3/

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely risky. Since MutationRecords are batched up, the current state of the DOM can make it difficult to determine the surrounding nodes for a mutation. For example, if you have two MutationRecords sent to the MutationObserver, the second MutationRecord might have deleted the surrounding nodes for the first one, which means you can't do it by *simple* DOM inspection.

To make the problem concrete, take this html:

```
<ul><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li></ul>
```

And this javascript:

```
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
while (ul.lastChild) ul.removeChild(ul.lastChild);
```

The mutation observer would get two mutation records, and you'd have to do some fancy legwork to figure out that they were connected. I'm not sure what that algorithm would look like, or whether it would be possible in every situation.

Anyway, here's my example jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/theazureshadow/88egh/

Maybe you could do something easier or smarter if you could limit the cases that your MutationObserver had to handle.